# How to check if std::ratio_multiply overflows?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I need a function that will give me type of 'std::ratio_multiply' if no overflow, or list of original ratios types if overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sufficient condition would be checking that the log of the numerators and denominators sum to less than the log of `std::numeric_traits<std::intmax_t>::max()`, but that excludes some things that would cancel to representable values.

That can be improved by considering gcds

```
template <typename R1, typename R2, bool>
struct safe_ratio_multiply_impl;

template <typename R1, typename R2>
struct safe_ratio_multiply_impl<R1, R2, true>
{
    using type = std::ratio_multiply<R1, R2>;
}

template <typename R1, typename R2>
struct safe_ratio_multiply_impl<R1, R2, false>
{
    using type = std::tuple<R1, R2>;
}

constexpr intmax_t log(intmax_t number, intmax_t acc = 0) {
    return number <= 1 ? acc : log(number / 2, acc + 1);
}

constexpr bool is_safe_multiple(std::intmax_t N1, std::intmax_t D1, std::intmax_t N2, std::intmax_t D2)
{
    auto limit = log(std::numeric_traits<std::intmax_t>::max()) + log(std::gcd(N1, R2)) + log(std::gcd(N2, R1));
    auto num = (log(N1) + log(N2)) < limit;
    auto den = (log(R2) + log(R2)) < limit;
    return num && den;
}

template <typename R1, typename R2>
using safe_ratio_multiply = typename safe_ratio_multiply_impl<R1, R2, is_safe_multiple(R1::num, R1::den, R2::num, R2::den)>::type;
```